# Praying for Jesus?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, prayer, virgin-mary

I'm trying to understand the meaning of prayers, But not just to see it as a communication with God, but more as a unity with Him.

That's why I would like to ask if Jesus' mother Mary, or His relatives, were praying for Him during his lifetime for protection, strength or other necessities. Is there an official Catholic doctrine as to whether these prayers were necessary or meaningful as Jesus was indeed full of grace?

Is there any record of any such prayers?

Praying for Jesus sounds like nonsense, but not praying for him sounds ridiculous too...

Please, I'm only interested in the Catholic perspective, thanks.

Comment: Grasper, could you elaborate why do you think *praying for Jesus* sounds like nonsense? And what kind of prayer are you asking about? I will recommend you this page: http://www.gotquestions.org/types-of-prayer.html It lists different types of prayers which are supported with verses from the Bible. You may take a look there and I hope that it will be able to help you edit your question to have it re-opened. That is, if it is a genuine request that does not sound like it is condescending the other denominations. We all *edify the Body of Christ*.

Comment: This is not an answer but just a very tentative observation.  Mary and Joseph presented Jesus in the temple, as required by the law (Luke 2:22-24), even though His divinity would surely justify an exception to the law in His case. Extrapolating from that, I suspect that they also did the other things that parents normally do for their children, even when His divinity would make those things unnecessary (or perhaps even ridiculous). And I suppose that would include praying for Him.

Comment: Do not know why this question was closed as opinion based when some Catholic theologians have spoken on this very specific topic. Is not praying the Our Father imply that we pray for the Kingdom of Jesus to increase.